# I'm using a WPF TextBlock but then text gets cut off when it's too long. Is there an AutoScroll feature?

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock

My TextBlock has for example 50x50 pixels to display text, however if there is more text, I want a user to be able to scroll. Is there an autoscroll feature for this control?

Should I use a different control better suited for this task?

Here's a couple of pics to illustrate the problem:

**This one works fine because the text fits in snugly:**
[image]

**This one doesn't seem correct. Text is cut off.**
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just in case someone comes into the same problem. Just wrap the textBlock with a  control. Works like a charm!

```
<ScrollViewer Background="Black">
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockBackStory" 
               FontSize="12" 
               Foreground="Orange" 
               TextWrapping="Wrap"                       
               Background="Black" 
               TextDecorations="None">
                            Backstory here.
    </TextBlock>      
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: That's exactly right, just wrap it in a scrollviewer. I often end up setting the horizontal scrollbar to auto too

Answer (score 1):

You can put your textblock inside a ViewBox, so the font will adjust to display the entire text.

Comment: that might end up shrinking the font smaller than you can see. It is a valid option, but I think a scrollviewer will be a better choice in many situations